# How to find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+ e^{in\pi} -i)^n z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+ e^{in\pi} -i)^n z^n$

I try using root test to find the ROC, and I ended up with this limit:

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |1+ cos(n\pi) + i (sin(n\pi)-1)| $

I know $sin(n\pi)$ is just going to cancel out since it is 0 for all n. But my problem is with cos. This will make the limit undefined.

How do I find the ROC of convergence then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the radius of convergence is the following quantity:
$$
\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|1 + e^{in\pi} - i|^n}} = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}|1 + e^{in\pi}-i|}.
$$
The values of $e^{in\pi}$ for $n = 1,2,3,4,\dots,$ are $-1,1,-1,1,\dots.$ Hence the values of the sequence $|1 + e^{in\pi}-i|$ for $n = 1,2,3,4,\dots,$ are $1,|2-i|,1,|2-i|,\dots = 1,\sqrt{5},1,\sqrt{5},\dots.$ The $\limsup$ of that sequence is $\sqrt{5}$, so the radius of convergence of the original series is $1/\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Oh yeah I could use Cauchy Hadamard’s, thanks this is a great help!